# How to use separate connection strings for Application and Migrations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to get an ASP.NET Core 2 with EntityFramework Core 2.0 application up and running. As part of it, also looking to start using Migrations to manage data model changes.

Here is my appsettings.json file where I am storing connection strings. For keeping things simple here, I left the user/pwd open. In real scenario, encryption will be used. Main goal is to use two separate connection strings. One for Application usage, where the user account TestAppServiceAccount will be used only to perform reads/writes (DML operations only). Another one called DbChangeServiceAccount for applying migrations (DML + DDL operations).

```
{
  "SqlServerMigrationsConnection": "Server=SqlServerInstance;Database=TestDb;User Id=DbChangeServiceAccount; Password=xyz$123;",
  "SqlServerAppConnection": "Server=SqlServerInstance;Database=TestDb;User Id=TestAppServiceAccount; Password=xyz$123;"
}
```

Here is how my Startup.cs is setup. Based on my understanding, looks like both application and Migrations are going to depend on the same connection string that is passed in startup.cs to AddDbContext method.

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            var userServiceSqlConnection = Configuration["SqlServerAppConnection"];
            services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(optiopns => optiopns.UseSqlServer(userServiceSqlConnection));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Just wondering how do I pass a different connection strings, one that will be used purely for application and another one for just applying migrations?

Comment: Yeah create an implementation of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation#from-a-design-time-factory and make it access a different connection string. Pretty sure you can override (or it is at least planned) a conenction string in the dotnet ef commands

Comment: @Mardoxx, What you mentioned is also interesting, definitely can be used in some advanced use cases. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting this question, I realized that, I could make use of multi environment setup. 
So for migrations I will have a separate environment that will be used to manage CI/CD activities. I feel like this is a deployment concern, 
So I could simply create appsettings.migrations.json or something similar and fall back to use just one connection string for both Application and Migrations. And my Startup.cs AddDbContext parameters will stay same.

My appsettings.development.json will look like

```
{
  "SqlServerAppConnection": "Server=SqlServerInstance;Database=TestDb;User Id=TestAppServiceAccount; Password=xyz$123;"  
}
```

My appsettings.migrations.json will look like

```
{
    "SqlServerAppConnection": "Server=SqlServerInstance;Database=TestDb;User Id=DbChangeServiceAccount; Password=xyz$123;"
}
```

[How to manage multiple environments in asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments) from Microsoft has more details.

Comment: Is this really the best approach?  The credentials for your migrations (which would have higher privileges) will be published when you deploy your app. There must be a better way to keep these separate - and off of the web server.